# Threading with priority queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to test threads in python, so I tried to create 3 threads that run at the same time but each one prints a different letter from A - C.

It was easy so I added that the letters would be printed from first to last and I'm getting confused from here.
How can I make 3 threads that run talk to each other and to know when to print and when to not print?

the output should be:

```
A B C A B C A B C A B C
```

my code:

```py
import threading
import time
import queue

val = 0


def increment(letter):
    global val
    for x in range(100):
        val += 1
        lock.acquire()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(val, letter, ' ')
        lock.release()


lock = threading.Lock()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=('A',))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=('B',))
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=('C',))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any reason to use threads for this, if only one thread should ever be doing something, and the things must be done in a specific order.

Comment: its for practice, I am just wondering how you can do it with threads.

Comment: It would make more sense to practice using threads for something that it makes sense to use threads for.

Comment: While threading isn't quite suitable for what you're trying to do, I get why you're trying to do it. Look into the producer/consumer model for threads. Instead of the threads communicating with each other, the main block, the one that starts the threads, coordinates the threads' activities through a series of queues.

Comment: thank you @sj95126 I went over some great guides on YouTube.